# delete PostgreSQL Table using python and pandas

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas

I want to delete all the contents in all PostgreSQL Table through python and pandas.

Here is my code:

```
from ftplib import FTP
import os
import csv
import psycopg2
import pandas as pd
abc=[]
conn = psycopg2.connect (xxxx,xxxx,xxxx)

abc=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Desktop/Paramter_Generation
/check_2.csv',header=None,index_col=False)

for names in abc[0]:
    table='DELETE * FROM radio_parameter.'+abc+';'
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(table)


cursor.close()
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

I use a csv call check_2.csv to list all the table name in PostgreSQL and use Pandas to read it. And save all the table name content using a DataFrame abc[].

Then I use for loop to delete all the table.

I got a error here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\p4532\Desktop\Paramter_Generation\delete_table.py", line 21, 
in <module>
cursor.execute(table)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\sql.py", line 26, in <module>
import sys
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 955, in 
__nonzero__
.format(self.__class__.__name__))
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, 
a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Can anyone help how to debug?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure to use `abs` at this line: ```table='DELETE * FROM radio_parameter.'+abc+';'```?

Comment: oh!!!!!! I got a stupid error. Thanks!